# Internet Explorer 8 is not showing background on a div CSS issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, stylesheet

I tried removing everything on the class, using the style directly over the div, but on internet explorer 8 it's refusing to show,it does work on ie9+, chrome, safari and firefox, any hints would be great!

```
.classDiv{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px 0;
  width: 928px;
  height: auto;
  background: url(images/perfbg.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / cover;
}
```

The html is simple

```
<div class="classDiv">lot's of stuff in here</div>
```

Comment: IE8 [does not support background options like "cover"](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts). You might want to try this [polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill).

Comment: did you notice that your class in CSS doesn't match with your class in HTML ?? classDiv not = to girlbox

Comment: sorry, they do match on the code :P @dippas

Comment: @showdev it doesn't work like background: url(images/perfbg.jpg); either.

Comment: I'm sure, I copied the url and paste it on the browser, and tried on ie 9, ie 11, chrome, safari and firefox (the height:1000px didn't work)

Comment: @showdev I just tried just keeping this background: url(http://full-url-path/picture.jpg) no-repeat; and nothing!, and it does work on the rest of the browsers

Comment: That's strange. It's difficult for me to test because I am not running IE8. If you have the IE developer tools, you could check whether that CSS definition is being dropped. Unfortunately, I'm not much more help.

Comment: I'm on a unix os my self :(, I'm testing on virtual machines because the customer ask for ie 8 to work perfectly, and I'm struggling, will keep trying to fix it